# python3 unpickling error in second iteration of for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I'm getting a strange error unpickling files in a for loop (python v3.6.8, pickle v4.0).  I made a class, pickled some of these class objects, and have a list of filenames for the pickled objects `files = [str_file1, str_file2, ...]`.  I want to open and unpickle each of them in a for loop.

```
<class definition for objects>
for fn in files:
   f = open(fn,'rb')
   object = pickle.load(f)
   f.close()
   <do some computation on the loaded object>
```

This works fine for the first loop iteration, but on the second iteration it throws: `_pickle.UnpicklingError: NEWOBJ class argument isn't a type object`.  After reading around, it seems like this error is most commonly thrown when the class that you're unpickling isn't defined.  But that doesn't seem to hold in this case, as it works fine on the first loop iteration.  To make sure the issue wasn't anything specific to the second file (such as it being corrupted, etc.) I ran:

```
<class definition for objects>
for fn in files[1:]:
   f = open(fn,'rb')
   object = pickle.load(f)
   f.close()
   <do some computation on the loaded object>
```

and again, it works fine on the first loop iteration (which was the file it failed on in the previous case) but throws the same error on the second iteration.  This seems like quite strange behaviour to me, but am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I would guess that your `<do some computation>` code is overwriting the class definition used by the pickled objects with something else.  Search for assignments to the same name as the class.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. There must be something missing here.

Comment: Wow that's embarrassing, thanks @jasonharper that was the issue.